# How can I, in a JQuery function, define a value then call another function and use the value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example, I have the function isPercentage, that uses a value defined in whatever function in which isPercentage is called:

```
isPercentage=function(){
        if (value<1){
            value=value*100;
            console.log(value);             
            $(this).val(value);
        }else if(value>100){
            value=value/100;
            $(this).val(value);
        }       
}



$("#userDiscount").change(function(){
        var value=$(this).val();
        isPercentage(); 
});
```

However, when a change occurs on $("#userDiscount"), I get a "value is not defined" error. How do I define "value" in such a way that isPercentage() can then pick it up.

Thanks!

Comment: JavaScript has **lexical scope**. What you are trying to do would involve **dynamic scope**, which none of the popular languages implements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call a function, it executes in *its own* context.  This means that when `isPercentage()` is called, the `this` value inside is ***different*** than outside that function.

`isPercentage()` has no idea what `value` is (since it's out of scope) and `this` is not what you think it is.  You need to tell that function what those values are.

First off, you should pass `value` as a *parameter* to `isPercentage` so it can use that value.  Second, you should have it *return* a value so you can set `$(this).val()`.

```
var isPercentage = function(value){
    if (value<1){
        value = value*100;
    } else if(value>100){
        value = value/100;
    }       
    return value;
};

$("#userDiscount").change(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    value = isPercentage(value);
    $(this).val(value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I might do it slightly differently to Rocket by capturing the actual element inside the function instead. I'd probably change the name of the function so that it made sense in this context.

```
function processValue(e) {
  var element = e.currentTarget;
  var value = $(element).val();
  if (value < 1) {
    value = value * 100;
    $(element).val(value);
  } else if (value > 100) {
    value = value / 100;
    $(element).val(value);
  }
}

$("#userDiscount").on('change', processValue);
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/qnfxspuj/10/)